# Standard function to do filtering of objects and setting values

Tags: javascript

I find myself doing this over 15 times with different lists in my controller.

```
var selected = vm.countryList.filter(function(obj){return obj.id == vm.country})
if (selected.length) { selected[0].ticked = true }

var selected = vm.languageList.filter(function(obj){return obj.id == vm.language})
if (selected.length) { selected[0].ticked = true }

var selected = vm.propertyList.filter(function(obj){return obj.id == vm.property})
if (selected.length) { selected[0].ticked = true }
```

Would it be possible to write a nifty little function so I just call it like:

```
setTick(vm.property, vm.propertyList);
```

Or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, did you try to see how your implementation for `setTick` works ?

Comment: It should just do like the two lines I write over and over and over :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
function setTick(propertyName) {
  var selected = vm[propertyName + 'List'].filter(function(obj) {return obj.id == vm[propertyName]});
  if (selected.length) { selected[0].ticked = true }
}
```

and the use it like that :

```
setTick('language');
setTick('country');
```

In ES6 :

```
const setTick = (propertyName) => {
  const selected = vm[`${propertyName}List`].filter(obj => obj.id == vm[propertyName]);
  if (selected.hasOwnProperty('length'))
    selected[0].ticked = true
}

// You can also use it like the following :

['language', 'country', 'property'].forEach(propName => setTick(propName));
```

Hope it helps, 
Best regards

Comment: Boehm are you some kind of genius hacker or what? Heheh that solution cuts like 200 lines of code from my controller :-D  Thanks!!!  Really cool ES6 version btw, I kind of understand what you are doing :-D